# Can I detect if a user erases device via APNS Feedback?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, feedback

I have an application that uses the APNS Feedback Service to detect when a user has uninstalled my iOS application.

If a user erases the device rather than uninstalling the application, how will the Feedback Service know to report to me that my application is no longer installed on the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't.

As far as I know, the Feedback Service merely reports that the device doesn't want any more notifications from your app. This might happen if someone disables notifications for your app or disables them entirely.

As for erased devices, presumably at some point they contact APNs with their device certificate and list of apps and APNs notices. Or maybe they don't, and APNs unregisters the device after it hasn't heard from it in a month.

While the feedback service may be a strong indicator of app uninstalls, I have no idea how accurate this data is. What are you using it for?