# Can i detect if an ios app unregistered from APN

Tags: c#, php, ios, web-services

I have a webservice to send push notification to ios devices. Can i know if my ios application is uninstalled from the ios devices  because i will contact my client app via sms if they are uninstalled.. is that possible ?

Comment: This strikes me has a shady thing to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Can I detect if a user erases device via APNS Feedback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341623/can-i-detect-if-a-user-erases-device-via-apns-feedback?rq=1) it doesn't report to you that it's inactive. Instead the feedback will report that the device doesn't want to receive further messages when you attempt to send them one.